# SQL select combine data from multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, report, common-table-expression

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
ID    OLD      NEW      TIME
1       a       b       5
1       b       c       7
1       c       d       45
1       d       e       4
2       a       b       1
2       b       d       8
2       d       e       45
3       b       c       15
3       c       d       14
```

And I would like to build a report that looks like this (basically for each OLD data point grab the TIME value):

```
ID    TimeForA    TimeForB  TimeForC    TimeForD    
1     5           7         45          4
2     1           8         NULL        45
3     NULL        15        14          NULL
```

I have been able to get all the data into the correct columns, but have not been able to combine each row into a single row for each ID. My current query looks like this (no I don't have every column in place yet, still just testing):

```
WITH CTE (id, ATime, BTime) 
AS 
(
    select T1.oid, T1.loggedFor, null, T1.time as Atime
    from Table1 T1
    where T1.OLD = 'a'
    union
    select T1.oid, T1.loggedFor, T1.time as BTime, null
    from Table1 T1
    where T1.old = 'b'  
)
select ID, ATime, BTime
from CTE
order by ID
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Comment: Added the SQL server 2008 tag, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, 
    sum(if(old = 'a',time,null)) as time_for_a,
    sum(if(old = 'b',time,null)) as time_for_b,
    sum(if(old = 'c',time,null)) as time_for_c,
    sum(if(old = 'd',time,null)) as time_for_d
from test_tbl
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!